# jQuery.browser.msie depreciated in 1.9 trying to fix in Drupal 7

Tags: theming, javascript

The design template I am using needs jQuery 1.9. But Drupal 7 doesn't seem to support 1.9. Please correct me if I'm wrong
The issue is that when in import jQuery 1.9 in Drupal 7 then here is the following error when in admin (overlay) trying to add content:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

This is coming from `overlay-parent.js`. It has the following code:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version, 10) < 8) {
```

It's causing an error because I am importing jQuery 1.9 and Drupal 7 runs code that contains the deprecated and removed `jQuery.browser` method.

The problem is that, after updating the code in  `modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js` to:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i) && navigator.userAgent.match(/7/)) {
```

These changes are not taking effect. Perhaps this has to be compiled into some minimized `.js` file but I am not sure. How to make these changes in Drupal 7? Any alternative ways to make jQuery 1.9 compatible Drupal 7?

Comment: If you have not turned on JS aggregation no need to minify js. To debug you can always print out `navagator.userAgent` to check if its working or not. 

Also as David mentioned, there might be other code which are using deprecated code. To check that you can use [`jQuery.migrate plugin`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). It will indicate in console places where deprecated code are used.

Comment: Thank you 2-Stroker...the suggestion of JQuery.migrate worked very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal ships with a particular version of jQuery.

Using a different version of jQuery means refactoring various core javascript code.

If you want to use a more recent jQuery version, you can check the available versions provided by the [jquery_update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module which provides that refactored replacement javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I didn't want use lower Jquery version, so I resolve problem with  `#2` tiny patch in [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1961178)